# Run sqlite query using connect_db() method 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, sqlite, methods

I'm having issues using the method I made to connect to my sqlite db. I get an error of `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'`, when i call `connect_db()` below:

When i try to use `connect_db()`

```
def connect_db(dbname):
    try:
        dbconn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    except:
        print ("error connecting to db")
```

It throws the error here:

```
        #save to database
        dbconn = connect_db('./syncdb.db')
        cursor = dbconn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE paths (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                source TEXT, 
                destination TEXT
            ) 
        ''')
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've tried a lot of different ways already to use this method `connect_db()`, but it doesnt seem to be able to work correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue? Try not catching all exceptions, see which exception is raised. Your indentation is a bit messy too, maybe it's just a paste error though.

Comment: The issue is, i cant access the connection/creation/ of syncdb.db created in connect_db() when i try to get it lower down in my script. How do i access it?

Comment: Please see my updated code/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return the connection; otherwise the function returns `None`

```
def connect_db(dbname):
    try:
        dbconn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    except:
        print ("error connecting to db")
    return dbconn
```